# Repeat rows based on on a string and replace values of the new rows

Tags: r

I'm having difficulties with this problem.

```
df <- data.frame(number=1:3,name=c('a','b','c'),code=c("5464","5463,5678","45363,6346,6435"))
```

If the 3rd column has only 1 set of numbers, don't repeat. For those which have > 1 set of numbers, repeat the row and replace with the subsequent number.

Original output

```
  number name    code
   1      a      "5464"
   2      b      "5463,5678"
   3      c      "45363,6346,6435"
```

Desired output

```
number name code
  1     a  "5464"
  2     b  "5463"
  2     b  "5678"
  3     c  "45363"
  3     c  "6346"
  3     c  "6435"
```

I really don't know where to start. I tried using `stringr::str_split_fixed` to separate the strings and count the number of occurrences. But after that I'm having difficulties in repeating the rows based on these occurrences and replacing with the corresponding value.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df, code)
```

---

Or `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "code", ",", "long")
```

Comment: The second one works fine!  The first function doesn't seem to exist according to R documentation.

Comment: @user3617958  It is in the new tidyr version i.e. 0.6.0.  It works fine for me. Which version of tidyr you have.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using 0.4.1. Must be that.